# How to unit test and send messages to embedded broker?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, jms, activemq-artemis

I need to run an embedded ActiveMQ Artemis.

Having this code:

```java
ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("vm://localhost?broker.persistent=false");
    
Session session = connectionFactory.createConnection().createSession();
MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(null);
    
JmsRequest jmsRequest = new JmsRequest("jsonMsg", JmsRequestStatus.NEW, "targetQueueTESTTEST");
    
Topic topic = session.createTopic(jmsRequest.getTargetQueue());
TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage(jmsRequest.getJsonMsg());
producer.send(topic, message);
```

**Returns me this exception:**

```
javax.jms.JMSException: Failed to create session factory    
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createConnectionInternal(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:886)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:299)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:294)
    at com.americanwell.caretalks.jms.entities.PracticeITTest.aaa(PracticeITTest.java:17)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:230)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:58)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.invm.InVMConnectorFactory
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.ClassloadingUtil.newInstanceFromClassLoader(ClassloadingUtil.java:59)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl$2.run(ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:1002)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl$2.run(ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:999)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl.instantiateConnectorFactory(ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:999)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl.<init>(ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:181)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ServerLocatorImpl.createSessionFactory(ServerLocatorImpl.java:781)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createConnectionInternal(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:884)
```

How can I solve this issue? How can I get the session from the embedded broker?

Comment: Any feedback here? Did you ever sort this out?

Answer (score 1):

The main problem here is this:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.invm.InVMConnectorFactory
```

You need to put `org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.invm.InVMConnectorFactory` on your classpath so the application an use it. This class is in the `artemis-server` Maven module, e.g.:

```xml
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
   <artifactId>artemis-server</artifactId>
   <version>2.13.0</version>
</dependency>
```

If you're constructing your classpath manually then just include the `artemis-server-<version>.jar`. It's shipped in the broker distribution in the `lib` directory.

Comment: After adding the dependency, I got an error message saying `Caused by: org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.core.ActiveMQNotConnectedException: AMQ219007: Cannot connect to server(s). Tried with all available servers.`

Comment: @HaozheXie, you should create a new question about this rather than commenting on this one which is a different use-case as far as I can tell. Thanks!